# URL doesn't change after changing ui-router state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have followed the documentation and online tutorials to create my ui-router states however when I enter my state, the URL doesn't update. Same happens when I do `$state.go('main.about-me');` for example. The state changes but not the URL. Is there something wrong with my config that I can't see clearly?

Will be thankful for any tips. Thanks.

```
'use strict';
angular
    .module('myApp.config', ['ui.router'])
    .config(routes)
    .run(['$rootScope', '$location', '$stateParams', '$state', appRun]);

function routes($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('main', {
            url: 'main',
            abstract: true,
            views: {
                '': {
                    templateUrl: 'main/main.tpl.html',
                    controller: 'mainController as vm'
                },
                'nav-bar@main': {
                    templateUrl: 'main/nav-bar/nav-bar.tpl.html',
                    controller: 'navigationBarController as vm'
                }
            }
        })

    .state('main.home', {
        url: '/home',
        views: {
            'content': {
                templateUrl: 'home/home.tpl.html',
                controller: 'homeController as vm'
            }
        }
    })

    .state('main.about-me', {
        url: '/about-me',
        views: {
            'content': {
                templateUrl: 'about-me/about-me.tpl.html',
                controller: 'aboutMeController as vm'
            }
        }
    })

    .state('main.contact-me', {
        url: '/contact-me',
        views: {
            'content': {
                templateUrl: 'contact-me/contact-me.tpl.html',
                controller: 'contactMeController as vm'
            }
        }
    });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('');
}

function appRun($rootScope, $location, $stateParams, $state) {
    console.log('run the app');
    console.log('$location', $location);
    console.log('$rootScope', $rootScope);
    console.log('$stateParams', $stateParams);
    $state.go('main.home');

}
```

Inside my body I have this

`<div ng-cloak>
    <div ui-view class="content-container"></div>
 </div>`

Comment: try to remove main from   .state('main.home', { .....
or 
try to $state.go('main.main.home');